# Returning value from Class Method in bridged Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift3, return-value

I'm trying to send and receive values to objective C from swift. I worked how to send even though i'm not quiet sure if its the most effeiciant bit of coding. I really stuck on returning values back to swift. I believe its a class method.

here is my current code
I think i can return multiple values using dictionary

I tried code like this

```
let Instance = pitchShift.pitchMethod(CGFloat(sendOne), sendTwo, indata)
let returnValue = Instance() -> (Int: returnMe)
```

but to no avail.
Thanks for reading and possibly helping

```
//  MainWindowController.swift

import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        let sendOne = 1.4
        let sendTwo:CLong = 4096
        let myArray:[Float] = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
        let indata:NSArray  = myArray as NSArray

        pitchShift.pitchMethod(CGFloat(sendOne), sendTwo, indata)

        print("\n out the other side")

    }//End of Overide

}//END OF THE WORLD
```

here is the bridging header

```
//PitchShift-Bridging-Header.h

#import "PitchShift.h"
```

Here is the header

```
//  pitchShift.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface pitchShift : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) id pitchProperty;

+ (void) pitchMethod: (CGFloat) sendOne :(long) sendTwo : indata;

@end
```

here is the Class Method I would like to return "returnMe" to swift

```
//PitchShift.m

#import "PitchShift.h"
#include <stdio.h>

@implementation pitchShift

// classmethod
+ (void) pitchMethod:(CGFloat) sendOne : (NSInteger) sendTwo : (NSArray*)pindata {

    /* main processing loop */
    for (long i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        NSArray *inDataArray = pindata;
        NSNumber *inNSnumber = inDataArray[i];
        float inDataFloat = [inNSnumber floatValue];;
        printf("\n %f %f %li %li",inDataFloat,sendOne,i,sendTwo);
    }//eo for

    long returnMe = 7;
    printf("\n returnMe = %li",returnMe);

}//End of the World


@end
```

Comment: Your Objective-C method `+ pitchMethod:sendOne:sendTwo:` does not return or store any values. You cannot receive values from a method which generates no result. You may need to clarify what value do you want to get.

Comment: I was using the "returnMe" as an example of what i needed returning to swift. I broke down my program to its bare essentials. Just so it made it easier to read and thus hopefully help. Eventually i would be using the link below as the C code and returning "outdata". I was hoping someone could assist by showing me how to return a single value and then i could work out the rest. [link](http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/repo/smbPitchShift.cpp)

Comment: Why don't you import the C-function straightly into Swift?

Comment: I was eventually going to do that but wanted to learn how to use C code by bridging. Eventually I was gonna re write in swift i just wanted to get it to work so i could understand things like FFT etc. And if i have a working program i think it would be easier to translate into pure swift.

Comment: Generally, `NSArray` does not work well with Swift Arrays like `[Float]`. And something holding "state" (in your case `outdata`) is not appropriate to be a class method. Include the link into your question, and describe what you eventually want to do. Your example Objective-C code is far from your actual purpose and readers who only read your question may not find the right solutions.

Comment: my whole program is really quiet big as it includes all sorts of audio. I thought it would be easier for someone to read. Should i really post all the code i have ?? Is it not possible to answer the question as is. buy maybe re phrasing is a just returning a single value. like k for example

Comment: I am not saying to show all your code. Copy only the link and what you eventually want to do in your comments into the question. Comments are not considered to be a part of question and not many readers follow all comments. With updating your question, it gets higher precedence in the "active" list and more readers would read the updated part.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quiet understand what you want me to do. Please excuse me I'm a retired person pushing 68 years old who does this for a hobby and i'm very unaware of the etiquet in asking a question. I thought i was being quiet straight forward in my original post Hey Ho